# Is there a physical loopback cable for devices that don't have an audio loopback feature?

Tags: audio

It's schematic looks similar to this:

[image: schematic]

I want to record my PC's sound to a smartphone, but both devices only have a TRRS jack, so a splitter won't work.

Comment: Please provide more context than a schematic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @human_rosas I want to record my PC's sound using my phone.